# How to add parameters in a query string using input type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I work with the api new york times search engine, my question is simple, i just want to change parameters in my url using a input type text in my html. 
How can i do that ?
End date and sort are one of the parameter, i just want to know how can i change the string with an input field in html.
here a copy of my code :

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="nyt.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="font.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="grille.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
       <button type="submit" id='searchButton'></button>
       <input type="text" id='searchTerm' placeholder="search">
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='nyt.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js :

```
var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
var searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchButton');
url += '?' + $.param({
  'api-key': "[API KEY]",
  'end_date': "19440606",
  'sort': "newest"
});
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: 'GET',
  q: searchTerm,
}).done(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
}).fail(function(err) {
  throw err;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of your input field with the “value” property, like so:

```
var searchTerm = document.getElementById('searchButton').value;
```

See also: [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendRequest(searchTerm) {
  var url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json";
  url += '?' + $.param({
    'api-key': "[API KEY]",
    'end_date': "19440606",
    'sort': "newest"
  });
  console.log(searchTerm);
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    q: searchTerm,
  });
}

document.querySelector('#searchButton').addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var query = document.querySelector('#searchTerm').value.trim();

  if (query.length > 0) {
    sendRequest(query)
      .done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      }).fail(function(err) {
        throw err;
      });
  }
})
```